# Run Custom Test Task in Gradle without recompiling

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle custom Test task to run my Integration Tests. I would like to be able to run this without Gradle automatically going through all previous phases and just running the test. Is there a way to do this without -x for each build step?

Comment: Is it of type Test, in other words like this: task integrationTest(type: Test)

Comment: @judoole, Yes, exactly..

Comment: I guess not extending from Test then. It is dependent on compile and that other stuff.  Maybe experiment with JavaExec? #answeringfromabar